# [SOLVED]Normalization not working on input buffer. How to solve this?

Tags: arduino-nano

I wrote a piece of code that takes input from a sensor which is called the World Famous Pulse Sensor from Analogue Pin 1 and stores it in an Array with 127 elements then finds the largest in it, divides the rest by the largest, multiplies by 64 which is the maximum y length on my OLED and prints it onto the OLED.
It still gives me pre-normalized and scaled values on Serial Plotter.

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code.

```
#include <U8glib.h> 
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(12, 11, 8, 9, 10);
int x, y;int Buffer2[128];
void pageBP();
const int pageCount = 1;
int p;
void (*pages[pageCount])() = {pageBP};
int duration [pageCount] = {1000};
void setup() {
  
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
  u8g.setColorIndex(1);
  p = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop() {
  
 


u8g.firstPage();
  do {  
    (*pages[p])();
  } while( u8g.nextPage() );
  delay(duration[p]);
  p = p+1;
  if (p == pageCount)
    p=0;
}


void pageBP() {
  for(x = 0;x < 128;x++) {
Buffer2[x] =(analogRead(A1)>>2);//IP for PPG
Serial.println(Buffer2[x]);
delay(5);
}
for(int i = 1;i < 128; i++)
    { 
       if(Buffer2[0] < Buffer2[i])
           Buffer2[0] = Buffer2[i];
    }
    for(int i = 1;i < 128; i++)
    {
       64*(Buffer2[i]/Buffer2[0]);        
    }
  for(x = 0;x < 127;x++) {

u8g.drawLine(x, Buffer2[x], x, Buffer2[x+1]); //OP to OLED for ECG

u8g.drawLine(64, 0, 64, 63); 
u8g.drawLine(0, 32, 128, 32);}
for(x=0;x<128;x+=8) 
u8g.drawLine(x, 31, x, 33);
for(x=0;x<64;x+=8)
u8g.drawLine(63, x, 65, x); 
u8g.drawFrame(0, 0, 128, 64); 
}
```

Here is Garbage Graph.
[image]

Comment: `64*(Buffer2[i]/Buffer2[0]);` : this line does absolutely nothing. You're not storing the result of that computation anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will point out some problems with your code:

- Look at this line:

  ```
    64*(Buffer2[i]/Buffer2[0]);
  ```

  It doesn't do anything. You calculate a scaled value, but you are not saving it anywhere. You need to assign that value to a variable (like an element in a new array).
- With this code

  ```
    for(int i = 1;i < 128; i++)
    { 
        if(Buffer2[0] < Buffer2[i])
            Buffer2[0] = Buffer2[i];
    }
  ```

  You are overwriting the first value in your buffer to find the highest value. That might not be a problem for you, but to be clean here, you should just use a new variable, that holds the highest value outside of the buffer.
- I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this line:

  ```
    u8g.drawLine(x, Buffer2[x], x, Buffer2[x+1]);
  ```

  Normally, you would want to draw a line from one point in the graph to the next. So the second x parameter would need to be the x value for the next point. Currently you are just drawing a vertical line. I would instead write

  ```
    u8g.drawLine(x, Buffer2[x], x+1, Buffer2[x+1]);
  ```

  since you already are only counting to 127 instead of 128.
- Even if you get the above right, the Serial Monitor would still show the unscaled values, since you are printing to Serial directly after measuring. So to display the scaled values in the Serial Monitor, you need to move the line

  ```
    Serial.println(Buffer2[x]);
  ```

  down to after the scaling, for example in the same for loop as the OLED display code.
- And finally you should really fix your indentation. That will make your code way more readable and thus better understandable. The Arduino IDE even has an autoformat feature, that you could use for that.